# wordpress TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, conflict

I want to use the javascript code here : http://jsfiddle.net/BQxw4/40/

So I added the script before body closing tag in the footer.php.

However, when I go to the page I can see the following error on console (Mozilla firebug.)

TypeError: $ is not a function
$(document).ready(function() {

After a quick google research I came to know that it has something to do with the jQuery and $ conflict so I replaced $ with jQuery everywhere in the code which I added from fiddle.

but again when I went back to the homepage and refreshed it, The console gave me this:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).autocomplete is not a function
```

minLength: 2

I even tried replacing $ with $$ but no luck.

Please help me friends.
Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: `autocomplete` is not part of the jQuery API. It's part of the jQueryUI plugin.

Comment: Hey thanks, It worked I added The jQuery UI before my script and the errors gone. It now says TypeError: c.element.propAttr is not a function
 

...d("keydown.autocomplete",function(g){if(!(c.options.disabled||c.element.propAttr...

Comment: Hi, I changed theJquery UI version fromone on the fiddle to the "1.11.1" and it worked like charm. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You have to download and include jQuery in your project, or just use google apis:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this, however as its wordpress, I see the jquery library already loaded under NET in the console.

Comment: I just tried adding it before the fiddle code, but no luck I got the same error.